# Fix Dual Boot Install Alongside option not appearing on win 10 pro pc

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

About three years ago I set up dual boot, however my SSD died recently and I find myself back to the same point in time.

I reinstalled win 8, upgraded to win 10 home and then I went the extra mile an upgraded to win 10 pro.

If followed the everyday linux guide [here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside_8.html)

I shrank the volume to free up 70GB for Ubunutu.

I then booted into the 14.04.3 image on a USB stick and clicked install.  However, I do not get an install alongside option.

The options are as follows

1. Erase disk and install Ubuntu
2. Encrypt the new Ubuntu
3. Use LVM
4. Something else

Why am I not seeing install alongside Win 10?  Is it ok to just select the something else option?

Comment: You can use the `Something else` and install Ubuntu along side it that way.  Good instructions can be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).  Make sure that you install the bootloader to the primary boot drive, i.e. `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose <kbd>Something else</kbd> and select the partition you created.
Set `/` (root) as the mount point and select `ext4` as the file system.
After installation, select Ubuntu as default system in BIOS.

Important :

Disable hibernation and fast boot in Windows before.
Open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the "old" version of Windows Control Panel.
Go to the Power Settings and uncheck Fast startup.
Shut down the computer completely, do NOT reboot.

Comment: Just going over old questions I asked.  I can't remember what I did but this solution looks good so accepting.